# How do I add more python modules to my yocto/openembedded project?

Tags: python, linux, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I wish to add more python modules to my yocto/openembedded project but I am unsure how to?  I wish to add flask and its dependencies.

Answer (score 22):

some python packages having corresponding recipes in the meta folders, like Enum class for example:

`meta-openembedded/meta-python/recipes-devtools/python/python-enum34_1.1.6.bb`

unfortunately lot's of useful classes aren't available, but some might be needed for the python application. get used of installing missing packages using `pip` already on booted platform? but what if the target product is not IP network connected? the solution is to implement a new recipe and add to the platform meta layer (at least). Example is a recipe for the module `keyboard` useful for intercepting keys/buttons touch events:

1. use PyPi web site to identify if the package is available:

`https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/`

2. download archive available on the package description page:

`https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/archive/master.zip`

3. collect some useful information required to fill-out a new recipe:

   - SUMMARY - could be obtained from the package description page
   - HOMEPAGE - the project URL on github or bitbucket or sourceforge, etc
   - LICENSE - verify license type
   - LIC_FILES_CHKSUM by executing `md5sum` on existing `LICENSE` or `README` or `PKG-INFO` file located in the root of the package (preferrably)
   - SRC_URI[md5sum] - is `md5sum` of the archive itself. it will be used to discover and download archive on pypi server automatically with the help of supporting script `inherit pypi`
   - PYPI_PACKAGE_EXT - if the package is not `tar.gz` require to supply the correct extension
4. create missing `python-keyboard_0.13.1.bb` recipe:

`

```
SUMMARY = "Hook and simulate keyboard events on Windows and Linux"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard"
LICENSE = "BSD-3-Clause"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://PKG-INFO;md5=9bc8ba91101e2f378a65d36f675c88b7"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = "d4b90e53bbde888e7b7a5a95fe580a30"
SRC_URI += "file://add_missing_CHANGES_md.patch"

PYPI_PACKAGE = "keyboard"

PYPI_PACKAGE_EXT = "zip"

inherit pypi
inherit setuptools

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"
```

`

5. the package has been patched by adding

`SRC_URI += "file://add_missing_CHANGES_md.patch"`

directive to the recipe due to missing `CHANGES.md` file used by `setup.py` script to identify package version (this step is optional). the patch itself has to be placed inside the folder next to the recipe matching recipe name but without version:

`python-keyboard`

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! Works perfectly. This should be accepted as the correct answer, a little explanation of `BBCLASSEXTEND` would be nice.

Answer (score 22):

This question is old, but currently in 2020 there is a python package called `pipoe`.

`pipoe` can generate `.bb` classes corresponding to python packages for you!

Usage:

```
$ pip3 install pipoe
$ pipoe -p requests
OR
$ pipoe -p requests --python python3
```

Now copy the generated .bb files to your layer and use them.

https://pypi.org/project/pipoe/

Comment: This didn't work for me; `$ pipoe -p v4l2 --python python3` output: `Failed to translate license: GPLv2`. Solved it with setting license manually: `$ pipoe -d GPLv3 -p v4l2 --python python3`

Comment: In 2023 pipoe did not work properly out of box for me, some pypi json changes forced me to check out the newer [pwicks86 fork of pipoe](https://github.com/pwicks86/pipoe).  I needed plumbum for gatesgarth, but latest toml version was not supported by the old yocto so I wanted to use `pipoe --version` with older plumbum that still used setup.py. And then I had to edit some : back to _ in the bb file.

Answer (score 3):

The OE layer index at layers.openembedded.org lists all known layers and the recipes they contain, so searching that should bring up the meta-python layer that you can add to your build and use recipes from.

Answer (score 1):

In your Image recipe you can add a Python module by adding it to the `IMAGE_INSTALL` variable:

```
IMAGE_INSTALL += "python-numpy"
```

You can find possible modules for example by searching for them with wildcards:

```
find -name *python*numpy*bb
```

in the Yocto Folder brings:

```
./poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python/python-numpy_1.7.0.bb
```

Answer (score 0):

The pipoe did not work for me either, I ended up making this bash script. Someone else might find it useful.

You will need to change this in my script below:

```
local my_layers_dir="my/layers/directory"
```

To run this script:

```
./pypi.sh <modulename>
#example:
./pypi.sh humanfriendly   #this should generate the bb file for the humanfriendly python module
```

pypi.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

function argstovars()
{
  for change in $@; do
      set -- `echo $change | tr '=' ' '`
      eval $1=$2
  done
}

function main(){
    
    local module=""
    argstovars $@
    local my_layers_dir="my/layers/directory"
    
    local url_files="https://pypi.org/project/$module/#files"
    mkdir -p /tmp/pypi
    rm -fr /tmp/pypi/*
    pushd /tmp/pypi
    
    wget $url_files
    local targz_url=$(cat index.html | grep https://files  | grep tar.gz | sed -r "s/<a href=\"(.*)\">/\1/g")
    wget $targz_url
    local targz_file=$(ls  | grep tar.gz)
    local md5=$(md5sum $targz_file)
    md5=${md5%% *}
    local sha256=$(sha256sum $targz_file)
    sha256=${sha256%% *}
    tar -xf $targz_file
    local module_with_version=$(echo "$targz_file" | sed -r "s/(.*)\.tar\.gz/\1/g")
    pushd $module_with_version
    local license_file=$(find . -name LICENSE*)
    local md5lic=$(md5sum $license_file)
    md5lic=${md5lic%% *}
    popd
    popd

    module_with_version="${module_with_version//-/_}"; echo $foo
    mkdir -p "$my_layers_dir/$module"
    pushd "$my_layers_dir/$module"
    
    echo "SUMMARY = \"This is a python module for $module\"
HOMEPAGE = \"https://pypi.org/project/$module/\"
LICENSE = \"MIT\"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = \"file://$license_file;md5=$md5lic\"

SRC_URI[md5sum] = \"$md5\"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = \"$sha256\"

PYPI_PACKAGE = \"$module\"

inherit pypi setuptools3

RDEPENDS_${PN} += \" \
    python3-psutil \
\"
" > "${module_with_version}.bb"

    popd
}

time main module=$@
```