# How to add python modules in yocto build

Tags: python, yocto, recipe

I want to add this python modules into my build image (*yocto* rocko release):

- python cyclone,
- python txaio,
- python txJSON-RPC,
- python hyperlink.

I was used *recipe tool*, and tried the following link:
[How do I add more python modules to my yocto/openembedded project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862088/how-do-i-add-more-python-modules-to-my-yocto-openembedded-project)

But *yocto* fails on parsing content stored in local configuration file (local.conf).

How to add these or any python package ?

```
$ cat local.conf 

MACHINE ??= 'var-som-mx6'
DISTRO ?= 'fslc-x11'
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"
CONF_VERSION = "1"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " tcpdump"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-pip"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " firefox"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " sqlite3"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-pysqlite"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " zlib"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " libpcre"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " openssl"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-redis"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-tornado-redis"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " nginx"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-jsonschema"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " jsonrpc"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-tornado"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-singledispatch"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-pyopenssl"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-pycparser"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-pyasn1"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-ipaddress"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-idna"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-futures"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-functools32"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-enum34"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-cryptography"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-cffi"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-certifi"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-backports-abc"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-asn1crypto"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-setuptools"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-twisted-core"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-automat"
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " python-txaio"

LICENSE_FLAGS_WHITELIST += "commercial_libav commercial_x264"
DL_DIR ?= "${BSPDIR}/downloads/"
ACCEPT_FSL_EULA = "1"

...
following error comes
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'python-txaio' (but /home/administrator/var-fslc-yocto/sources/meta-variscite-fslc/recipes-fsl/images/fsl-image-gui.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
```

I have added a recipe similar to *python-six* for *python-txaio* and added respective *txaio-18.7.1.tar.gz* binary into downloads folder.

Thanks.

Comment: show us your `local.conf`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk

Comment: This error tell's You exactly what is wrong, *bitbake* is not able to find in any layer (configured in bblayers.conf file) recipe with name: *python-txaio* that is required by *.fsl-image-gui*. You have to write/create a recipe for this python module, not just add downloaded binary tar file into *downloads* dir.

Answer (score 1):

Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61206443/5470638), you can use `pipoe` to add .bb-files for a specific python module:

```
$ pip3 install pipoe
$ pipoe -p txaio
```

..or for Python 3:

```
$ pip3 install pipoe
$ pipoe -p txaio --python python3
```

And then just copy the generated .bb-files to your layer.

https://pypi.org/project/pipoe/