# How to add/install pygame to Yocto project on Raspberry Pi 4?

Tags: python, pygame, raspberry-pi, yocto

How can you install pygame to your yocto project? Can only seem to find old solutions that doesn't seem to work. I mange to install python3 without any issues, but the meta-python layer doesn't contain pygame as standard. How can you create your own layer/recipe to get pygame?

Tried to create my own recipe from the script [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38862088/how-do-i-add-more-python-modules-to-my-yocto-openembedded-project)
but when I use `bitbake add-layer <PATH>`
I get an error saying that:
`Specified layer directory <PATH> doesn't contain a conf/layer.conf file`

```
SUMMARY = "Python Game Development"
HOMEPAGE = "https://www.pygame.org"
AUTHOR = "A community project. <pygame@pygame.org>"
LICENSE = "LGPL-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://setup.py;md5=59f9a291287e87473bbb98f2c9291c5c"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/9a/50/67767e5586a45e7e7b02e6f0e07853f8fcb81b54c66db6278f1a1344491f/pygame-2.1.2.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "8467a125e9075fa701f082806d228366"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "d6d0eca28f886f0477cd0721ac688189155a587f2bb8eae740e52ca56c3ad23c"

S = "${WORKDIR}/pygame-2.1.2"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = ""

inherit setuptools3
```

How my other files look.
**local.conf:**

```
MACHINE ??= "raspberrypi4-64"
RASPBERRYPI_DISPLAY = " 1"
IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " python3"
IMAGE_FSTYPES = "wic wic.bmap"
```

**bblayers.conf:**

```
  <PATH>/poky/meta \
  <PATH>/poky/meta-poky \
  <PATH>/poky/meta-yocto-bsp \
  <PATH>/meta-openembedded/meta-oe \
  <PATH>/meta-openembedded/meta-python \
  <PATH>/meta-raspberrypi \
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that worked for me:
Add `meta-python` and `meta-netoworking` via `meta-openembedded`.
In local.conf add `IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " python3-pip"`.
While up and running use the command `pip3 install pygame`

Comment: Another solution was to download the pygame wheel and add it to the build then run it when yocto is up and running.

Answer (score 0):

Have you managed to add pygame to Yocto? I'm trying to achieve the same thing.

I've also tried generating a recipe with pipoe. (Without creating a custom layer. I've added the recipe to *../sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/python*.) The recipe is parsed successfully, however the compilation fails.

This is my python3-pygame_2.1.3.dev8.bb:

```
SUMMARY = "Python Game Development"
HOMEPAGE = "https://www.pygame.org"
AUTHOR = "A community project. <pygame@pygame.org>"
LICENSE = "LGPL-2.0"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://setup.py;md5=f28719c8b1d7e19071bd25e2f3a54c06"

SRC_URI = "https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f0/34/fc13b596b637cc59961ed606447a27a96d31bfda3ca965b73ebd16a02750/pygame-2.1.3.dev8.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "6cf32b59a453b9824f421065a0205b52"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = "94d98328e73d56be35cc3ae8e31f9d95fbce4f3dca6a74f05c58f4c5ef18c33d"

S = "${WORKDIR}/pygame-2.1.3.dev8"

RDEPENDS_${PN} = "libsdl2"

inherit setuptools3
```

Comment: Hello, I managed to install pygame. But not via the build of the image. I installed pip3 in local.conf with IMAGE_INSTALL:append = " python3-pip". When I booted up and connected to the internet I ran the command pip3 install pygame, which worked!